# Running event function after event has been set up

Tags: events, jquery

This will do it:

```
$('input').on('change', function(event){
  ...
}).change();
```

...but what if there is another plugin installed that hooks some function on the change event? I'll trigger that function too, and it may not be desirable. How can I avoid such conflicts?

Comment: Create a custom event then..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [namespaced events](http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events)

```
$('input').on('change.myevent', function(event){
  ...
}).trigger('change.myevent');
```

This will get triggered on normal `change` events (*along with other `change` handlers on it*) but will also be triggered by `change.myevent` (*only it*)

This will also allow you to unbind only your own event in case you need to ..